# How can I execute code when exiting a thread

Tags: java, multithreading, dispose, teardown

I want to execute code at the very end before a thread dies. So what I am looking for is some kind of dispose(), tearDown() method for threads guaranteeing that certain tasks are performed before exiting the thread.

Comment: Id is hard to say how you can change your thread without having informations about it. For instance is it daemon thread? How its task looks like? Is task executed in infinite loop? How are you handling for now thread interruption?

Comment: it's a task in a threadPoolExecutor, implemented as Runnable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap the code to be executed in a separate thread in your own code that has a `try`/ `finally` block, and call the `run` method of the "real" `Runnable` from the `try`, like this:

```
final Runnable realRunnable = ... // This is the actual logic of your thread
(new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            realRunnable.run();
        } finally {
            runCleanupCode();
        }
    }
})).start();
```

The code of `runCleanupCode()` will be executed in the same thread that was used to run the logic of your actual thread.

Comment: Yeah, AKA 'if you want some code in a function to be executed last, put it at the end' :)

Answer (score 3):

The other answers don't take into account that you are talking about a Thread Pool.  Here's what you'd need to do:

```
private static class MyThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory {
    public Thread newThread(final Runnable r) {
        return new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    r.run();
                } finally {
                    // teardown code
                }
            }
        };
    }

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ThreadPoolExecutor exec = new ThreadPoolExecutor(10, 20, 100, TimeUnit.SECONDS, null, new MyThreadFactory());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Taking dasblinkenlight's answer a little further (too far?):

```
class ThreadWithCleanup extends Thread {
    final Runnable main;
    final Runnable cleanup;

    ThreadWithCleanup(Runnable main, Runnable cleanup) {
        this.main = main;
        this.cleanup = cleanup;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            main.run();
        } finally {
            cleanup.run();
        }
    }
}

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable m = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Hello from main.");
                throw new RuntimeException("Bleah!");
            }
        };
        Runnable c = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Hello from cleanup.");
            }
        };
        ThreadWithCleanup threadWithCleanup = new ThreadWithCleanup(m, c);
        threadWithCleanup.start();
        try {
            threadWithCleanup.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        }
    }
}
```

And I used to think I would never see a legitimate reason to extend the Thread class!